# Is there an equivalent to Python yield's behavior in Groovy?

Tags: python, groovy

Trying to learn Groovy, and it's been a fun and only slightly confusing adventure so far.  What I'm currently trying to do is stand up a server, make a `wget` request to it and when that request is received, have a certain action be executed - in this case, just creating a new file:

```
import java.net.http.HttpResponse

class ServerLogic {
    static def holdupServer() {
        println('Standing up server..\n')
        def socketServer = new ServerSocket(5000)
        // server is up
        socketServer.accept { socket ->
        // the lines below only execute when a connection is made to the server
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            println("[${new Date()}] HELLO\n")
            def newFile = new File("/home/nick/IdeaProjects/groovy_learning/resources/new.txt")
            newFile.createNewFile()
            newFile.text = 'Hello!!!'
            println("NEW FILE SHOULD HAVE BEEN CREATED.")
            println ">> READ: ${input.newReader().readLine()}"
        }
    }
        return HttpResponse
    }

}

ServerLogic.holdupServer()
```

With the above code, when I execute a `wget http://localhost:5000`, it "works" in the sense that the file is created like I want it to be, but the `wget` output is unhappy:

```
--2021-07-17 15:42:32--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2021-07-17 15:42:33--  (try: 2)  http://localhost:5000/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... failed: Connection refused.
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... failed: Connection refused.  
// these occur because the server has shut down after the last println call, when the `return HttpResponse` triggers
```

So from that, we can reason out that there isn't a proper response being returned, even though I have the `return HttpResponse` after the `sockerServer.accept ...` logic. My thought on how to solve the problem (primarily because I come from a Python background) would be to somehow mimic `yield`ing a response in Python (basically, return a response without breaking out of the `holdupServer()` logic and thus breaking the server connection).  Is there a way to achieve this in Groovy, or is there a different approach I could use to essentially return a valid `HttpResponse` without exiting the `holdupServer()` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

You can use a [function callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), which in Groovy translates to a closure callback. Basically, you pass the value you want to return to another function/method defering the stack on the current method. This approach works essentially on all languages. In java (the versions which don't support lambda), for instance, you would have to pass an object in which you would call a method later.

##### Example

```
import java.net.http.HttpResponse

class ServerLogic {
    static def holdupServer(Closure closure) {
        (0..2).each {
            closure.call(HttpResponse)
        }
    }
}

ServerLogic.holdupServer { httpResponse ->
    println httpResponse
}
```

##### Output

```
interface java.net.http.HttpResponse
interface java.net.http.HttpResponse
interface java.net.http.HttpResponse
```

#### Addressing OP's comment

You have to provide some headers. At least `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` should've been provided along with the data and HTTP status (HTTP/1.1 200, in this case) properly formatted. Also, you should've wrapped the `ServerSocket.accept` calls in a while loop.

See the MDN [Overview on HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview).

##### Code

```
class ServerLogic {
    static HEADERS = [
      "HTTP/1.1 200",
      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",
      "Connection: Keep-Alive",
      "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000",
      "Content-Length: %d\r\n",
      "%s"
    ].join("\r\n")

    static def holdupServer(Closure callback) {
      println('Standing up server..\n')
      def socketServer = new ServerSocket(5000)
        // server is up
      while(true) { // Continue to accept connections
        socketServer.accept { socket ->
        // the lines below only execute when a connection is made to the server
          callback.call(socket) // call function
      }
    }
  }
}

ServerLogic.holdupServer { Socket socket ->
  String data = "RESPONSE <--\n"
  def response = String.format(ServerLogic.HEADERS, data.size(), data)
  println response
  socket << response
}
```

##### Client output

```
RESPONSE <--
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer! +1. This code, however, runs without me even needing to ping/wget the server once or multiple times - which isn't quite the intended behavior. The intended behavior would execute an action *only* when a ping is received. Would there be a way to preserve that part of my code?